# Take everything out of a file name except from numbers

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, filenames

So I have the file `3D_492.png` and I am trying to get rid of everything **but** the numbers after the last underscore. How would I go about this?

I want `3D_492.png` to become `492.png`

More examples:
`Anniversary_1_Purple_710.png` to become `710.png`

They are all in the folder `\Images`

Edit: **I'm dumb and forgot to say that I would like to rename the files with the new names.**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using split:

```
filename = "3D_710.png"
# create a list of the parts of the file name separated by "_"
filename_parts = filename.split("_")
# new_file is only the last part
new_file = filename_parts[-1]
print new_file
# 710.png
```

Full example including rename, assuming `Images` is relative to the directory containing our Python script:

```
from os import listdir, rename
from os.path import isfile, join, realpath, dirname

dir_path = dirname(realpath(__file__))
images_path = join(dir_path, "Images")
only_files = [f for f in listdir(images_path) if isfile(join(images_path, f))]
for file in only_files:
    filename_parts = file.split("_")
    # new_file is only the last part
    new_file = filename_parts[-1]
    rename(join(images_path, file), join(images_path, new_file))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you!

*Thanks to everyone else for answering too.*

Answer (score 3):

Perfect job for [`str.rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition):

```
>>> s = "3D_492.png"
>>> start, sep, end = s.rpartition('_')
>>> end
'492.png'
```

It is guaranteed to return three elements, which sum to the original string.  This means you can always get the 2nd element for the "tail":

```
>>> 'Anniversary_1_Purple_710.png'.rpartition('_')[2]
'710.png'
```

Putting the pieces together:

```
import os
os.chdir('\Images')

for old_name in os.listdir('.'):
    new_name = old_name.rpartition('_')[2]
    if not exists(new_name):
        os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, using `os.path.basename` and then `str.split` to extract characters after the final underscore:

```
import os

lst = ['3D_492.png', 'Anniversary_1_Purple_710.png']

res = [os.path.basename(i).split('_')[-1] for i in lst]

print(res)

['492.png', '710.png']
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want to split on `_` and ignore everything but the last result.

```
*_, result = fname.split("_")
# or:
# result = fname.split("_")[-1]
```

Renames are done using `os.rename`

```
for fname in fnames:  # where fnames is the list of the filenames
    *_, new = fname.split("_")
    os.rename(fname, new)
```

Note that if you want to do this with an absolute path (e.g. if `fnames` looks like `["C:/users/yourname/somefile_to_process_123.png", ...]` this will require more processing with `os.path.split`)

```
for fpath in fnames:
    *dir, basename = os.path.split(fpath)
    *_, newname = basename.split("_")
    newpath = os.path.join(dir[0], newname)
    os.rename(fpath, newpath)
```

Comment: Since they only want the last result, may want to consider `fname.rsplit('_', 1)[1]` as I believe it will be slightly faster

Comment: @chrisz could do, but it seems unnecessary (micro-optimizations, and all that). Note that indexing by 1 rather than -1 is slightly less robust (since it fails with an `IndexError` if the filename has no underscores)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to search for the digits preceding the extension.

```
import re

def update_name(name):
    return re.search(r'\d+\..*', name).group()

update_name('3D_492.png') # '492.png'
```